# SQL Server 2012 - search nvarchar field for > 1 like matches

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have a column containing strings called "Data" (defined as nvarchar(MAX) )

Data contains the following cells:

```
-------------------------------------
|                data                |
--------------------------------------
| "test data #item test data #match" |
-------------------------------------
| "test data #test"                  |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to create a query that searches for occurrences with #{something}. However the query returns rows with occurences of 2 or more. So would return:

```
-------------------------------------
|                data                |
--------------------------------------
| "test data #item test data #match" |
-------------------------------------
```

Since there are two hashtag items :

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%#% AND COUNT > 2
```

How would I go about writing such query?

Comment: Count the `#` in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`DATALENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) ([difference `LEN` vs. `DATALENGTH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151693/len-vs-datalength-in-sql-server-2005)):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE (DATALENGTH(data) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(data, '#', ''))) / DATALENGTH('#') >= 2
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8d6312bf319242fa4bba25616d640d31)

---

You can also [create a function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) on T-SQL to get a smaller query (and better reuse):

```
-- create the function GetStringCount
CREATE FUNCTION GetStringCount(@strValue VARCHAR(200), @charValue VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (DATALENGTH(@strValue) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@strValue, @charValue, ''))) / DATALENGTH(@charValue)
END

-- use the function GetStringCount
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE dbo.GetStringCount(data, '#') >= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where len(data) - len(replace(data, '#', '')) >= 2
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5f641/2)

Comment: There is a syntax error in your statement, may want to edit